# Can't deploy react app (issues with build folder)

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, path, production

So I have built a react app from scratch using `npx create-react-app`. Everything was going great and I decided to deploy it, to which I hit a lot of problems. Using BlueHost has the host, I accessed the CPanel and inserted the build folder, which i used `npm run build` to create. The website loaded correctly on chrome, however issues within Safari and Mobile browsers emerged, the page was empty.

After doing further research, I decided that the issue was in deployment and not dependencies. I came to this conclusion because I was able to run a local server on both Chrome and Safari, to which the website worked. If it was a dependency issue, it would not have worked on the local server.

So, I decided to start debugging the build folder. However, this is where an issue emerged, I could not load it at all on a server. I tried using `serve -s build`, but that directed me to an error screen, `404: the requested path could not be found`. If I try to plainly use the index.html, `open with browser` method on my build, it directs my to an empty page with an invalid url, `file:///Users/danieldobrovolskiy/Documents/optimal-exterior/build/index.html`.

Apologies if my question is vague or incoherent in someway. I'm seriously confused with the deployment process and have no idea what to even ask. All help is appreciated! Let me know if further information is needed.[

Comment: have you set homepage in package.json? it should be like "homepage": "./" if you're deploying off the main folder of webserver

Comment: That did it! It now works! Thank you so much! How do I accept a comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a homepage in package.json? it should be like "homepage": "./" if you're deploying off the main folder of the webserver